# Augmented Reality Desktop Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, augmented-reality

Can an augmented reality DESKTOP application be made on Unity or any other 3D engine using a webcam.? if yes, then what other extra tools and softwares are required?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done using Unity, take a look at ARToolkit, there are also a dozen of other tools.

[Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/15215/unity-3d-and-augmented-reality.html) you can find an old post about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create AR apps using Unity. I prefer using ARToolKit as it is open source. Have a look here for necessary downloads: http://artoolkit.org/download-artoolkit-sdk (scroll down to the "Download Unity Section")

Here you can find the documentation for using Unity with ARToolKit:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=6_Unity:unity_getting_started

Answer (score 1):

Vuforia does not support desktop for now. But artoolkit support.

And easyar supports.